# Rails: Production and Development system time messing up analytics metrics in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

My app uses the gem impressionist and I am recording impressions for my app.

Everything was working well until when I ran it on the production server.

Suddenly, all the metrics were 5 hours ahead of time (I'm in Toronto, EST time).

What is the appropriate way to show the data to the end user who is in Toronto? And what would be the best way to show the impression data to people in California? What would be the best method or algorithm to show the metrics in their local time?

I'm afraid that a user from California would see an increase in impression at 4 AM next day, but they are still at 8 PM the day before. That would not kill the app but it's definitely a weird user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much control over the timezones you would like your users to have.

For instance the simplest solution to your initial issue would likely be to just set the Rails apps default timezone to EST since your production server is probably set to UTC (the 5 hour difference).  Then simply stating somewhere that your times are based on EST explains to the user why the metrics lay out during the times of the day that they do.

For finer user control it can be nice to provide a preference that allows the user to set their own Timezone.  Then you use a filter in your application controller to set the timezone each request for the current user rather than a global configuration.  This may take quite a bit of time to go through your app and ensure that all times being displayed / parsed by the app are being displayed appropriately though.

Heres a brief article showing some actual code for these two methods http://databasically.com/2010/10/22/what-time-is-it-or-handling-timezones-in-rails/